# Apache Tomcat - Simple jar file deployment

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, maven, tomcat

Can I deploy a basic `jar` file created from `java` project in `Apache Tomcat server`?

**Steps Followed:**

1. Open eclipse oxygen. Create a new `Maven` Project.
2. Add simple "Hello World" code in `Main`.
3. Add simple "Selenium Webdriver script" in the test folder
4. Create a `POM` file with all the dependencies
5. Open the command line and run `mvn clean install`
6. "Hello World.jar" file was created in the target folder.
7. Started my `Tomcat server`.
8. Copied the above `jar` file in the `WebApps` folder
9. Then I opened the browser and type "https://localhost:8080/HelloWorld"
10. I couldn't see the "Hello World" but an error.

Can I really do a deployment like above? Or Should I be creating only the web application in order to deploy in `Tomcat`?

Please help!

Comment: https://localhost:8080/HelloWorld right..?

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat is a web container and server, and you can't deploy jar files on web servers. It seems that you're writing "Hello World" code in main method and not creating a web application.

For tomcat deployment, you need to create a web application(using JSP/Servlet/Spring etc) and need to package same as WAR or EAR.

You can do packaging through maven as follows:

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```